# codility challenge, test case OK , Evaluation report Wrong Answer

Tags: java

the aluminium 2014 gives me wrong answer [3 , 9 , -6 , 7 ,-3 , 9 , -6 , -10] got 25 expected 28

but when i repeated the challenge with the same code and make case test it gives me the correct answer

Your test case [3, 9, -6, 7, -3, 9, -6, -10] : NO RUNTIME ERRORS (returned value: 28)

what is the wrong with it ???

the challenge :-

> A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. A
>   pair of integers (P, Q), such that 0 ≤ P ≤ Q < N, is called a slice of
>   array A. The sum of a slice (P, Q) is the total of A[P] + A[P+1] + ...
>   + A[Q]. The maximum sum is the maximum sum of any slice of A. For example, consider array A such that:    A[0] = 3
>       A[1] = 2
>       A[2] = -6
>       A[3] = 3
>       A[4] = 1 For example (0, 1) is a slice of A that has sum A[0] + A[1] = 5. This is the maximum sum of A. You can perform a single swap
>   operation in array A. This operation takes two indices I and J, such
>   that 0 ≤ I ≤ J < N, and exchanges the values of A[I] and A[J]. To goal
>   is to find the maximum sum you can achieve after performing a single
>   swap. For example, after swapping elements 2 and 4, you will get the
>   following array A:    A[0] = 3
>       A[1] = 2
>       A[2] = 1
>       A[3] = 3
>       A[4] = -6 After that, (0, 3) is a slice of A that has the sum A[0] + A[1] + A[2] + A[3] = 9. This is the maximum sum of A after a single swap. Write a function: class Solution { public int solution(int[] A);
>   } that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A of N integers, returns
>   the maximum sum of any slice of A after a single swap operation. For
>   example, given:    A[0] = 3
>       A[1] = 2
>       A[2] = -6
>       A[3] = 3
>       A[4] = 1 the function should return 9, as explained above.

and my code is :-

```
import java.math.*;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        if(A.length == 1) 
            return A[0];
        else if (A.length==2)
            return A[0]+A[1];

        else{
            int finalMaxSum = A[0];

            for (int l=0 ; l<A.length ; l++){
                for (int k = l+1 ; k<A.length ; k++ ){

                    int [] newA = A;
                    int temp = newA[l];
                    newA [l] = newA[k];
                    newA[k]=temp;

                    int maxSum = newA[0];
                    int current_max = newA[0];
                    for(int i = 1; i < newA.length; i++)
                    {
                        current_max = Math.max(A[i], current_max + newA[i]); 
                        maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, current_max);
                    }

                    finalMaxSum = Math.max(finalMaxSum , maxSum);

                }
            }

            return finalMaxSum;
        }
    }
}
```

i don't know what's the wrong with it ??

Comment: What was wrong with [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110259/codility-challenge-test-case-ok-evaluation-report-wrong-answer)?

Comment: This is O(n^3) btw.. It asks for an O(n) solution..

Comment: @KshitijBanerjee yes,  also this code doesn't work.  Also think in O(n) solution ;-)

Comment: Tests are executed backwards sometimes, at least when the input is a single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in the website and this is the reply from the support team

the evaluation system run your program not only on the test case it presented to you, but also on the mirrored test case B = [-10, -6, 9, -3, 7, -6, 9, 3]. On test case B your program indeed returned 22, when it should have returned 28.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static int findMaxSumOfArray(int[] A) {
    int[] T = new int[A.length];
    int sum = 0;

    int max1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max3 = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max1index = 0;
    int max2intex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] < 0) {
            T[i] = sum;
            sum = 0;
        } else if (i == A.length - 1) {
            sum += A[i];
            T[i] = sum;
            sum = 0;
        } else {
            sum += A[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < T.length; i++) {
        if (max3 < T[i]) {
            if (max2 < T[i]) {
                if (max1 < T[i]) {
                    max2intex = max1index;
                    max3 = max2;
                    max2 = max1;
                    max1 = T[i];
                    max1index = i;
                } else {
                    max3 = max2;
                    max2 = T[i];
                    max2intex = i;
                }
            } else {
                max3 = T[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return max1 + max2 + (Math.abs(max1index - max2intex) == 1 ? max3 : 0);
}
```

Comment: You might consider adding some explanation rather than only posting a code block.

Comment: Plus answer scores 10%. Wrong.